# Trying to get data with Alamofire and swift 5

Tags: swift, api, alamofire

I want to load some [data](https://wger.de) with Alamofire

Thats is my class

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let count: Int
    let next: String
    let previous: String
    let results: [Übungen]
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Übungen: Codable {
    let id, category: Int
    let resultDescription, name, nameOriginal: String
    let muscles, musclesSecondary, equipment: Int
    let creationDate: String
    let language: Int
    let uuid: String
    let variations: Int
```

next would be my Protocol

```
protocol ÜbungenGateway {
    func fetch(completion: @escaping (Result<[Übungen], Error>) -> Void)
}
```

and as the last part comes the Alamofireclass

```
class ÜbungenAlamofireGateway : ÜbungenGateway  {
    
    let url = "https://wger.de/api/v2/"       
  
    func fetch(completion: @escaping (Result<[Übungen], Error>) -> Void) {
    
  AF.request(url)
      .validate()
          .responseJSON {
            switch $0.result{
            case .success:
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let excercise = try! decoder.decode(Übungen.self, from: $0.data!)
                    completion(.success(excercise.name))
                }catch {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my Problem is that i get the following error:

```
"Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[Übungen]'"
```

at the line

```
completion(.success(excercise.name))
```

and i dont know why.

I hope someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

So the first issue is with type in completion block in `fetch` method.

```
func fetch(completion: @escaping (Result<[Übungen], Error>) -> Void)
```

Expected returned type in completion is a list of the `Übungen` object, but you are trying to pass name (which is a string) from `Übungen` object `completion(.success(excercise.name))`. That's why you are getting this error.

The second think is that you are calling `"https://wger.de/api/v2/"` endpoint and from [documentation](https://wger.de/api/v2/) the response will be a list of links and some properties from your object does not exist in the response.

Comment: could you give me a tipp how to fix it? i want the list all the excercises in a list

Comment: So you need to call this endpoint: `https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/` and Alamofire has method to Serialize JSON to codable object. ```AF.request(url).validate().responseDecodable(of: [Übungen].self) { response in   
  // and then on response.value you have your response struct
}```. And then pass whole `response.value` in completion block.